# Disable a button if an input field is bigger than another one

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am trying to check if an input A is bigger than input B and if this happens disable the button and if it's not enable

Html:

```
<input  v-model="form.a" />
<input  v-model="form.b" />
<button :class="{disabled: btnDisabled}">Enviar</button>
```

VueJs:

```
<script>
import { required, minLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';

export default {
    created() {
        
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            btnDisabled: false,
            form: {
                a: '',
                b: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkEndBillNumber() {
            if(this.form.a > this.form.b) {
                // I do not know what I should put here
            }
            else {
               // I do not know what I should put here
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

If you see I do not know what I should and in the vuejs conditional to disable the button if the conditional is true or false.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` attribute in buttons get `true` or `false` so you can do something like this:

```
<input v-model="form.a" />
<input v-model="form.b" />

<button :disabled="isDisabled">Enviar</button>
```

```
computed: {

 isDisabled() {
  const result = this.form.a > this.form.b ? true : false;
  return result;
 }

}
```

---

or if you want to add a class you can do this:

```
<button :class="{ 'yourClassName': isDisabled }">Enviar</button>
```